# Sqlalchemy query is very slow after using the in_() method

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

```
filters.append(Flow.time_point >= datetime.strptime(start_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
filters.append(Flow.time_point <= datetime.strptime(end_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
if domain_name != 'all':
    filters.append(Bandwidth.domain_name.in_(domain_name.split('|')))

flow_list = db.session.query(Flow.time_point, db.func.sum(Flow.value).label('value')).filter(*filters).group_by(Flow.time_point).order_by(Flow.time_point.asc()).all()
```

The query time is 3 to 4 seconds when domain_name is `'all'`, otherwise the query time is 5 minutes. I have tried to add an index to a column but to no avail. What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `domain_name` is not `'all'` you end up performing an implicit `CROSS JOIN` between `Flow` and `Bandwidth`. When you add the `IN` predicate to your list of filters SQLAlchemy also picks up `Bandwidth` as a `FROM` object. As there is no explicit join between the two, the query will end up as something like:

```sql
SELECT flow.time_point, SUM(flow.value) AS value FROM flow, bandwidth WHERE ...
                                                         -- ^
                                                         -- `- This is the problem
```

In the worst case the planner produces a query that first joins every row from `Flow` with every row from `Bandwidth`. If your tables are even moderately big, the resulting set of rows can be huge.

Without seeing your models it is impossible to produce an exact solution, but in general you should include the proper join in your query, if you include `Bandwidth`:

```
query = db.session.query(Flow.time_point, db.func.sum(Flow.value).label('value'))

filters.append(Flow.time_point >= datetime.strptime(start_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
filters.append(Flow.time_point <= datetime.strptime(end_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))

if domain_name != 'all':
    query = query.join(Bandwidth)
    filters.append(Bandwidth.domain_name.in_(domain_name.split('|')))

flow_list = query.\
    filter(*filters).\
    group_by(Flow.time_point).\
    order_by(Flow.time_point.asc()).\
    all()
```

If there are no foreign keys connecting your models, you must provide the `ON` clause as the second argument to [`Query.join()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.join) explicitly.

Comment: Thank you very much, I forgot to add a foreign key.